# Ubuntu 16.04.01 hebrew stops to work

Tags: language-support, input-language

I have very strange problem.
I use 2 languages - English and Hebrew
For some reason sometimes I cant write hebrew
I can switch between english and hebrew but even when hebrew choosen
it still types english.
Caps lock is not pressed.
When I logout and login it works.
I use GNOME as Windows manager.
Any idea how to solve this or, maybe how can I restart the language manager?

Comment: Please run the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window` and let us know what it outputs.

Comment: The answer is:  
false

Comment: Ok, then we can exclude that as an explanation. How do you switch layouts? Is an input source indicator shown at the top bar?

Comment: Switch by alt-tab, usually it works, but for some reason hebrew stops to work. It switches between layouts, but it writes english

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to do it back and forth a couple of times, maybe also with the GUI indicator?

Comment: Sure  
I think problem is with gnome. Now I switched to ubuntu native and it doesnt happen

Comment: Strange. I thought that Ubuntu (with Unity) and Ubuntu GNOME worked the same way in this respect.